# "Press ENTER or type command to continue" -writing second command returns to the editor mode

Tags: original-vim

When I write first command I get the "press enter or type command", even if I try to type second one it returns me to the editor mode, even though I would like to stay on console.

I am new vim user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I would like to stay on console

You have to press `:` then. Make sure you also read the corresponding Vim's help topic `:h hit-enter`

Also, you can switch into Ex mode ("console") permanently with `gQ` (enter `:vi` to get back).